# buildToolsVersion and compileSdkVersion had been deprecated

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, deprecation-warning

I've just noticed in a library module, that `compileSdkVersion` and `buildToolsVersion` had recently been deprecated. These are the two configurations, which it complains about (strikethrough text). This currently only affects `com.android.library`, not `com.android.application`:

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.library"
}
android {
    defaultConfig {
        compileSdkVersion 31
        buildToolsVersion "31.0.0"
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot: build.gradle]

When clicking through, one may notice that `com.android.build.gradle.AndroidConfig` had been deprecated in favor of `BaseExtension` (whatever that may mean for a matching `build.gradle`):

[image: Screenshot: Fernflower]

---

Apparently `compileSdkVersion` is now called `compileSdk` (this part seems to work) ...and `buildToolsVersion` has to be defined as a property. But when building (it's not that I've not tried), property `buildToolsVerson = "31.0.0"` is unknown:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        compileSdk 31
        buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
    }
}
```

How to make it build without deprecation warnings?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It builds alike this (the library module needs to be changed):

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
}
android {
    defaultConfig {
        compileSdkVersion 31
    }
}

plugins {
    id "com.android.library"
}
android {
    defaultConfig {
        // compileSdkVersion 31
        compileSdk 31
    }
}
```

Comment: It is no longer necessary to specify **buildToolsVersion** if you're using Android plugin for Gradle 3.0.0 or higher, because your project automatically uses a default version of the build tools that the plugin specifies.

Comment: @Amc: It never was necessary in Android Studio, but I prefer doing this to get reproducible builds, and I've had problems with the default on some machines rarely (in 99% cases it works).

Answer (score 80):

If you see this error **'compileSdkVersion' is deprecated**  For new SDK 33:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
   // compileSdkVersion 33
    defaultConfig {
        compileSdk 33
    }
...}
```

Comment: This one removed my warning. BUT, I do not get the logic behind: For "minSdkVersion" and "targetSdkVersion", the "Version" postfix is OK (and pretty meaningful to me). BUT in "compileSdkVersion", the "Version" postfix is a problem. Are Google product owners on drugs ?

Comment: I've changed "compileSDKversion" to "compile SDK", but buildToolsVersion = '30.0.3' is still deprecated. Should I delete the string " buildToolsVersion = '30.0.3' " completely?

Comment: Hi @bic55, You can safely remove `buildToolsVersion = '30.0.3'` because according to the documentation: _If you're using Android plugin for Gradle 3.0.0 or higher, your project automatically uses a default version of the build tools that the plugin specifies._

Comment: @Amc thanks for mentioning the documentation. For others to read it as well it's usually helpful to provide also the link where you fond it. I believe you found it here https://developer.android.com/build/releases/past-releases/agp-3-0-0-release-notes but the wording changed to: `Build Tools 26.0.2 or higher. With this update, you no longer need to specify a version for the build tools—the plugin uses the minimum required version by default. So, you can now remove the android.buildToolsVersion property.`

Answer (score 21):

```
compileSdk 33
buildToolsVersion = '33.0.1'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I've changed "compileSDKversion" to "compile SDK", but buildToolsVersion = '30.0.3' is still deprecated

Answer (score 9):

If you are using a kts gradle file instead (`build.gradle.kts`)

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
}
android {
    defaultConfig {
        // compileSdkVersion 31
        compileSdk = 31
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    defaultConfig {
        buildToolsVersion = '30.0.3'
        compileSdk = 31
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`buildToolsVersion` can be removed as it's no longer needed, and `compileSdkVersion`  should be replaced with plain `compileSdk` as per Google Android's own documentation.

https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/8.2/com/android/build/api/dsl/CommonExtension#compileSdkVersion(kotlin.Int)

> This function is deprecated.
> Replaced by compileSdk